# Aggregate multiple groupbys with a column of lists in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has a subset that looks like the following:

```
{u'snId': {3: u'396321357429208',
  695: u'606426623024865',
  703: u'606426623024865',
  914: u'606426623024865',
  5097: u'606426623024865',
  6865: u'396321357429208',
  26884: u'606426623024865',
  30538: u'396321357429208',
  32152: u'606426623024865',
  34314: u'396321357429208',
  34345: u'606426623024865',
  52207: u'606426623024865',
  55361: u'396321357429208',
  59077: u'606426623024865',
  68118: u'396321357429208',
  79366: u'396321357429208',
  86798: u'606426623024865',
  130472: u'396321357429208',
  146595: u'396321357429208',
  211110: u'606426623024865',
  227155: u'396321357429208',
  240219: u'396321357429208',
  245716: u'606426623024865',
  248525: u'606426623024865',
  327256: u'606426623024865'},
 u'snMsgType': {3: u'Private',
  695: u'Private',
  703: u'Private',
  914: u'Private',
  5097: u'Private',
  6865: u'Private',
  26884: u'Private',
  30538: u'Private',
  32152: u'Private',
  34314: u'Private',
  34345: u'Private',
  52207: u'Private',
  55361: u'Private',
  59077: u'Private',
  68118: u'Private',
  79366: u'Private',
  86798: u'Private',
  130472: u'Private',
  146595: u'Private',
  211110: u'Private',
  227155: u'Private',
  240219: u'Private',
  245716: u'Private',
  248525: u'Private',
  327256: u'Private'},
 u'tagIds': {3: array([198419]),
  695: array([201340]),
  703: array([198419]),
  914: array([198421]),
  5097: array([202750]),
  6865: array([199783]),
  26884: array([198419, 202750]),
  30538: array([198382]),
  32152: array([188101]),
  34314: array([198419, 198416]),
  34345: array([198419, 201340]),
  52207: array([201340]),
  55361: array([202750]),
  59077: array([198419, 198421]),
  68118: array([198422]),
  79366: array([188101]),
  86798: array([202750]),
  130472: array([198408]),
  146595: array([198419, 188101]),
  211110: array([198419, 199783]),
  227155: array([201340]),
  240219: array([198419, 199783]),
  245716: array([199783]),
  248525: array([198419, 198416]),
  327256: array([198419, 188101])},
 u'text': {3: u"No problem!",
  695: u"If you're struggling on what other shapewear to buy, then this article will help.",
  703: u"No problem!",
  914: u"No problem!",
  5097: u"No problem!",
  6865: u"No problem!",
  26884: u"No problem!",
  30538: u"No problem!",
  32152: u"No problem!",
  34314: u"No problem!",
  34345: u"No problem!",
  52207: u"No problem!",
  55361: u"No problem!",
  59077: u"No problem!",
  68118: u"No problem!",
  79366: u"No problem!",
  86798: u"If you're struggling on what other shapewear to buy, then this article will help.",
  130472: u"No problem!",
  146595: u"No problem!",
  211110: u"No problem!",
  227155: u"No problem!",
  240219: u"No problem!",
  245716: u"No problem!",
  248525: u"No problem!",
  327256: u"No problem!"}}
```

I want to do a groupby on the `snId`, `text` and `snMsgType` columns and aggregate all of the unique `tagIds` into a list for each group.

I've used the following:

```
df.groupby(["snId","snMsgType","text"]).agg({'tagIds': lambda x:  list(set(sum(filter(None, x), [])))})
```

However it doesn't work for the whole DataFrame as there are groups that only have 1 row and are not reduced. I get a `ValueError: Function does not reduce`. The challenge is to make this work for all groups regardless if it reduces or not.

My apologies for the somewhat confusing problem statement and big text block.

The answer will look something like this:

```
{'snId': {0: u'396321357429208', 1: u'606426623024865', 2:u'606426623024865'},
 'snMsgType': {0: u'Private', 1: u'Private', 2:'Private'},
 'tagIds': {0: [188101,
   199783,
   198408,
   198382,
   198416,
   198419,
   198422,
   201340,
   202750],
  1: [188101, 199783, 198416, 198419, 198421, 201340, 202750]},
  2: [201340, 202750]
 'text': {0: u"No problem!",
  1: u"No problem!",
  2: u"If you're struggling on what other shapewear to buy, then this article will help."}}
```

Comment: I think I understand your desired output, but could you include it in your post for clarity?

Comment: I added it in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tricked it using:

```
def aggr_tags(df):
    myagg = lambda s:tuple(i for i in zip(*s)) 
    # Group by snIds and aggregate all the tags ids used..
    df = df.groupby(["snId","snMsgType","text"]).agg({'tagIds': myagg})

    #convert back to lists.
    df['tagIds'] = df['tagIds'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x[0])))

    return df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you first need to expand your `tagIds` column of lists into separate rows, then you can perform your `groupby()` and `agg()`, where `my_dict` is your input `dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['tagIds']), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).astype(int)
s.name = 'tagIds'

df = df.drop('tagIds', axis=1).join(s)

g = df.groupby(["snId","snMsgType","text"]).agg({'tagIds': lambda x: x.tolist()})
```

Yields:

```
                                                                                                                         tagIds
snId            snMsgType text                                                                                                 
396321357429208 Private   No problem!                                         [198419, 199783, 198382, 198419, 198416, 20275...
606426623024865 Private   If you're struggling on what other shapewear to...                                   [201340, 202750]
                          No problem!                                         [198419, 198421, 202750, 198419, 202750, 18810...
```

This returns a MultiIndex dataframe. If you would like to return the results in the format in your edited question, you can do the following:

```
g.reset_index().to_dict()
```

Yields:

```
{'snId': {0: '396321357429208', 1: '606426623024865', 2: '606426623024865'}, 'snMsgType': {0: 'Private', 1: 'Private', 2: 'Private'}, 'text': {0: 'No problem!', 1: "If you're struggling on what other shapewear to buy, then this article will help.", 2: 'No problem!'}, 'tagIds': {0: [198419, 199783, 198382, 198419, 198416, 202750, 198422, 188101, 198408, 198419, 188101, 201340, 198419, 199783], 1: [201340, 202750], 2: [198419, 198421, 202750, 198419, 202750, 188101, 198419, 201340, 201340, 198419, 198421, 198419, 199783, 199783, 198419, 198416, 198419, 188101]}}
```

Comment: There should be one more row for the text "No Problem". There are two unique snIDs, and the "No problem" text has both represented.

Comment: That is the case here, it's simply a MultiIndex dataframe. You can use `reset_index()` on the result in my answer to verify. See my edit.

Comment: There are more rows in the dataframe that I am using (I can't put them all here), and this is still failing with a `ValueError: Function does not reduce`. 

On a related note, I did get this to work with my original code by editing the source code in groupby.py 2391 to 2393:
            if result is None:
                if (isinstance(res, (Series, Index, np.ndarray)) or
                        isinstance(res, list)):

to:

          if result is None:
                if (isinstance(res, (Series, Index, np.ndarray)) or
                        isinstance(res, None)):

Comment: You should always include a minimal, verifiable example in your question that captures all of your criteria.

Comment: Yeah my apologies, I didn't foresee, what is going on here, and I'm not really sure what is tripping it up using your code. I think it might be rows that have only 1 entry? As they cannot be reduced anymore.